# Large number of hits from IP addresses that reverse lookup to "cache.google.com"

Tags: google, ip-address, cache, web-traffic

We are seeing a large amount of server requests by IP addresses claiming to be cache.google.com and they are coming from all sorts of (unexpected) countries too. Currently the FW blocks servers that make too many connections. They are not users but it is Google trying to do something and not a human.

My question is: What are all these requests by "cache.google.com"? Why are the coming from so many different and unexpected countries? and what function am I blocking here from Google?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Similar issues:
https://support.google.com/mail/thread/16878288?hl=en
https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4863183.htm

Our company uses GSuite and we get the same issue when we send OTP emails that go to our 'catch-all' gmail address.  When one of our devs tries the link in the email, they discover that it's already been used!

We may try to block the IP addresses.